# Thoughts on SD552 pres compared to 7 series?

Tags: airshow

Hi all

Trying to hire a rig for the airshow and will probably only get to hire the SD552. Anyone had much experience recording with both 552 and 7 series gear? Are the mic pres the same? Is it much more fiddly to use?

Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 1):

There is [an article](http://www.sounddevices.com/notes/general/552-or-7-series/) published on the Sound Devices website that answers your exact question.
The 7-series outperforms the 552 in terms of the dynamic range (114 dB compared to 103dB respectively), which is more important when dealing with low-level recordings. 7-series recorders are also more flexible in terms of input routing. But the 552 is an excellent production mixer. As with any Sound Devices unit that I have used, the 552 is very intuitive so usability shouldn't pose you any problems.

Comment: Thanks Colin! The plan is to record aircraft so I doubt dynamic range will be tooo much of an issue :)